# Adobe Illustrator - How To Add Tick Marks Along a Path for Alignment

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6

I have a hobby where I create templates for foam armor. Up this point I have been using Inkscape and decided to try out Adobe Illustrator. In Inkscape, I can add a Path Effect to add ruler tick marks at set distances apart from each other with an offset. An example is shown below.
[image]

I can barely understand the Illustrator interface at this point. Worse, I cannot seem to find anyway to add path effect like this. Do I need a plugin for this? If so, can someone recommend one?

Comment: The distances between your markers seem to vary when followed along the whole shown black path. Is there some rule for the wanted distances? Or should every line segment have its own marker spacing? How the distance to a corner should be taken into the account? Should the method be valid also for curved forms or non-vertical and non horizontal straight lines? Is the actual wanted thing something else than an exact distance, for ex. an even distribution of the markers when the number of the markers on a segment is at first decided?

Comment: You could do this with patternbrushes. Quite easily. how do yu want to handle overflow?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real automated way to do this in Illustrator, but it *can* be done.
<sub>**This answer is using Illustrator CS6**, some of this may be more easily accessed in recent UI updates.</sub>

---

Merely add a *new stroke* via the **Appearance Panel** (`Window > Appearance`), then...

- Set the stroke to dashed and adjust...

[image]

If you want the marks to only protrude *into* the encompassing shape, after you've got the marks in place...

- Highlight the dashed stroke in the **Appearance Panel**
- Choose `Effect > Path > Offset Path` and enter a *negative* value for the `Offset`.
  <sub>Note there is a **bug in AI CS6** where the value field *may not accept* a negative value below 1 pica (1p0) and automatically converts any negatives to positives. For example, you **can't** enter `-0p4` it gets converted to `0p4` automatically when you leave the value field or click the OK button. But you **can** enter `-4pt`. So be aware you may need to be specific with negative values.</sub>

[image]

The *corners* are going to be squares, as in the images above. You *could* expand the appearance and then remove them. However, you will also lose any "live" editing ability as well. There may be other methods, such as pattern brushes which *may* work for your needs.

Although I've used points for the measurements here, you can use whatever system you need.

Comment: YOu could use a patternbrushthen you would not get the corner problems

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact sizes, then I'd use a different approach entirely with Illustrator. It's just two simple steps.

1. Use the Rectangular Grid Tool to make a grid like this shown below. In this example I've specified the size in mm, then set up the number of dividers so I get a  square grid, each being 10mm square.

[image]

2. Make a white filled rectangle with no stroke to hide the inside part of the grid.

[image]